# How do I reuse components that handle logic related to models in shell scripts for CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-model

So, **CakePHP** is a really awesome **MVC** framework, but I'm looking to better understand the MVC architecture in it, especially for services and organizing logic.

I currently have a lot of logic in *components* related to *models*, but I want to do some processing with that same logic in a *shell* script. I'm not sure if I'm approaching it correctly. I'm particularly concerned about technical debt and scaling maintainability. I don't want to go down this road then have to turn back. Thanks in advance for any and all pointers, best practice tips, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to move the component logic you mentioned into models.  Generally you want more of your logic in the model layer than the controller layer (which includes components).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've started to do, and it's working out great. Luckily for me CakePHP facilitates this quite easily, which confirms I made the right choice in framework. Nothing like getting an app up and running in a couple of hours, magic! :)